# figure factory won't load in colab

Tags: python, plotly, google-colaboratory

I have been trying to get figure factory to load for zip code locations on a map, I keep getting errors though, I've tried importing chart studio plotly and everything else and can make basic plots with plotly, but figure factory always gives this error: `$ pip install plotly-geo Or, install using conda with $ conda install -c plotly plotly-geo`
when I try to install conda related package I get this error:

```
/bin/bash: conda: command not found
/bin/bash: conda: command not found
/bin/bash: conda: command not found
```

from this:

```
!conda install -c plotly plotly-geo
!conda install -c conda-forge pyshp
!conda install -c conda-forge geopandas
```

I am unsure what to do, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

For plotly-geo you can try this

```
!pip install plotly-geo
```

If you also need pyshp and geopandas, you can also

```
!pip install pyshp
!pip install geopandas
```